# Running script in FreeBSD

Tags: scripting, freebsd

First steps in FreeBSD: trying to run my installation script. Fast help needed:

```
# ls
configure
# file configure
configure: Bourne-Again shell script text executable
# ./configure
./configure: Command not found
# configure
configure: Command not found
```

What is wrong, how can I execute this script?

Comment: what's the contents of `configure`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have bash installed? If not use FreeBSD Ports to install it. Use `where bash` to find out.

Comment: Really, bash is not installed. I guess I need to ask in SuperUser for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the force Luke :)

```
# pkg_add -r bash
```

Answer (score 1):

May it be, that your's *configure* script doesn't have appropriate executions rights. Try to cast:

```
chmod 777 configure
```

If it works, fix it to

```
chmod 764 configure
```

Answer (score 1):

`configure` scripts are ultra portable shell scripts. There is no need for bash here. The problem is somewhere else.

What's the first line in the configure script? Maybe a CR/LF snuck in, which is a common cause for a totally misleading error message saying that the script was not found, when it was the interpreter that was not found.

Please try `/bin/sh ./configure`

Answer (score 1):

First line of this script (`#!/usr/bin/bash`, i suppose) should be changed to `#!/usr/local/bin/bash`.
And of course, you should have shells/bash port installed.

Answer (score 1):

Install the bash package using

```
pkg add bash
```

or

```
make -C /usr/ports/shells/bash install clean
```

By default FreeBSD comes with tcsh and a POSIX compatible FreeBSD sh

On older FreeBSD systems you will need to do

```
rehash
```

before you can run it.